# WITH d AS (DELETE .... RETURNING entity_uuid,...)

Tags: postgresql

Есть Схема `reporter`. В ней 2 таблицы `queue` и `templates`. В обоих таблицах есть параметр `entity_uuid` и он одинаковый для шаблона и запроса(Т.Е если в очереди вызывается нужный шаблон подтягиваем его из templates).

Помогите по средством метода `WITH d AS (DELETE .... RETURNING entity_uuid,...)  SELECT * FROM d` удалить запись из таблицы `queue` и вернуть данные из `templates`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH r AS (
    DELETE FROM reporter.queue 
    RETURNING queue_object, report_params
)
SELECT 
  report_title,
  report_query,
  report_params,
  template_content,
  report_fill
FROM r
JOIN reporter.templates t ON r.queue_object = t.entity_uuid
```